# How can I count these duplicate integers?

Tags: java, arrays

**I must not modify the contents of the array, like using Array.sort().**

Expected return of this code is 6, because there are three duplicates of the value 1, one duplicate of the value 2, and two duplicates of the value 4. but mine is showing 10. I know the reason why it is 10: it's counting the duplicates multiple times.

How can I make this code check duplicate integer only once?

```
private int count = 0;

public void run() {
    int[] a = {1, 4, 2, 4, 7, 1, 1, 9, 2, 3, 4, 1};
    println(countDuplicates(a));
}

private int countDuplicates(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (a[i] == a[j]) { 
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Hint: this task could be made much easier using a `Map<Integer, Integer>` from element to element frequency, and traversing your array only once.

Comment: You can also use a set implementation ,while adding sth to set ,you can check whether you get true or false and increment the counter for duplicate.

Comment: I think (i) should be up to length-1

Comment: @K. Fred go through the values for(int j = 0; j<i; j++) and check if the number has already been a duplicate. I made an answer, but it got closed before I could click submit.

Comment: Only count upto the first following duplicate, then break out of j

Comment: As usual, it is not a duplicate of that question. Marked wrongly as duplicate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to take the current size minus the size with duplicates removed:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for (int i=0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    set.add(a[i]);
}

int numDuplicates = a.length - set.size();
```

There is probably a sleek way to populate a set of `Integer` from an array of primitive `int` using streams in Java 8.

Comment: Nice idea! Though it might not work for an Algo class. Also, many boxed objects (not that I care too much about that).

Comment: Not sure this works, presume `int []a= {1,1,1,1}`, would this subtraction not return 5 instead of 3?

Comment: My code would return 3 for your sample array (4, the size of the original array, minus 1, the size of the set).  That is, it would report _three_ duplicates, which seems correct to me.

Comment: I mistakenly thought you were still using some code from the question. If you're using Set to generate the list of unique values, it logically follows the remaining items must be duplicates. This is very clever.

Comment: Um, I didn't learn about 'HashSet' or 'set'(?)  Could you explain without using that please?

Comment: @K.Fred I gave what I perceive to be a good answer for your problem.  If your homework requires writing algorithmic code, then you'll have to do that, or use another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with simple to understand logic for leaners

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int []a ={1, 4, 2, 4, 7, 1, 1, 9, 2, 3, 4, 1};

    Map<Integer, Integer> occurances = new HashMap<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        //Check the is already occurred if not then add occurrence as 1
        if (!occurances.containsKey(a[i])) {
            occurances.put(a[i], 1);
        }
        // Second occurrences for a number
        else {
            occurances.put(a[i], occurances.get(a[i]) + 1);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(occurances);
    System.out.println("Total Numbers: "+a.length);
    System.out.println("Duplicate count is "+ (a.length - occurances.size()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array in-place.

Run through the array once, and count how many times current value is equal to previous value.

(Assuming you are allowed to use a library method to sort the array)

Comment: After the edit of the question, this answer is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int countDuplicates(final int[] a)
{
    int count = 0;
    Arrays.sort(a); // sort array, you can use any way for it
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == a[i + 1]) // check only next element
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count; // return 6
}
```

Comment: After the edit of the question it is evident that Arrays.sort(a) is not allowed..

Comment: Thank you! but I'm trying to solve it without Sorting .